# reflecting external changes to a model within a bound view/viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, design-patterns, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have a pretty standard view and view model. INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented in the vm using proxy properties to the underlying data across the various model objects (entities from EF).

That works fine for simple situations, however, the entities are likely to change by other code running within the application.  Because the entities don't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, any view showing the data at that particular time won't reflect the changes in data.

I'm thinking of wrapping the entities with some kind of observer that monitors changes to all the underlying properties and then the vm can work with the observer, rather than with the entity. However, this strikes me as requiring a fair amount of boilerplate code (and a lot of unnecessary duplication) to firstly wrap the entities in an observer, and then then secondly re-wrap the observer to create proxy properties in the vm.

This must be a common problem, but I can't find any real tidy solutions.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: One thing I saw being used well was using Castle DynamicProxy to wrap model objects and use the wrapped objects. You can read about it here. http://ayende.com/blog/4106/nhibernate-inotifypropertychanged (Ignore the `Interceptor` as it is NHibernate specific.). This matches what you need as long as you are ready to use wrapped objects in your VMs. Do keep in mind this works for properties only.

Comment: Thanks, yes this would be quite a good option.  I am using prism/unity so I have interception available to me.  To be honest though, I just implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on the business/model objects.  I realised I was trying to avoid doing it simply on principle, whereas this is a non-UI related reason for doing it, hence I think is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

It might benefit you to use the Mediator Pattern. It encapsulates how objects interact with each other.

By registering each view model to a 'Mediator' singleton class, there is a link between my view models. This means that all the view models I make the mediator class knows about. Then I can call a "notify" method on the mediator, sending an identifier to it.

When this notification comes through, the mediator can look attributes with that identifier placed on methods in other registered view models. If the attribute matches the identifier, it will run that method.

This is well documented through google on implementation details.

first link found:

http://www.dofactory.com/net/mediator-design-pattern

Comment: I think the Mediator pattern would be really overkill here. I have relatively light weight objects, and using a mediator would be an unnecessarily complicated way to resolve the issue.

Comment: No more complexity than an observer. It also requires less boiler plate code.